# Combine MySQL queries

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I am struggling to find away to combine these 2 queries... ive tried subquerys, joins, unions and have had no luck :(

Query A

```sql
SELECT DATE(crtdtime) AS cntldate, sd_class, COUNT(crtdtime) AS created
FROM master
WHERE DATE(crtdtime) = '2011-11-16'
GROUP BY cntldate, sd_class
```

Which produces

```
+------------+----------+---------+
| cntldate   | sd_class | created |
+------------+----------+---------+
| 2011-11-16 | CUST     |    2226 |
| 2011-11-16 | NET      |     238 |
+------------+----------+---------+
```

Query B

```sql
SELECT DATE(rstdtime) AS cntldate, sd_class, COUNT(rstdtime) AS restored
FROM master
WHERE DATE(rstdtime) = '2011-11-16'
GROUP BY cntldate, sd_class
```

Which produces

```
+------------+----------+----------+
| cntldate   | sd_class | restored |
+------------+----------+----------+
| 2011-11-16 | CUST     |     2315 |
| 2011-11-16 | NET      |      221 |
+------------+----------+----------+
```

But would like the end result to be...

```
+------------+----------+---------+----------+
| cntldate   | sd_class | created | restored |
+------------+----------+---------+----------+
| 2011-11-16 | CUST     |    2226 |     2315 |
| 2011-11-16 | NET      |     238 |      221 |
+------------+----------+---------+----------+
```

Would greatly appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
SELECT C.cntldate, C.sd_class, C.created, R.restored
FROM
(
SELECT DATE(crtdtime) AS cntldate, sd_class, COUNT(crtdtime) AS created
FROM master
GROUP BY cntldate, sd_class
) C
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT DATE(rstdtime) AS cntldate, sd_class, COUNT(rstdtime) AS restored
FROM master
GROUP BY cntldate, sd_class
) R
ON R.cntldate = C.cntldate AND R.sd_class = C.sd_class
WHERE C.cntldate = '2011-11-16' AND R.cntldate = '2011-11-16'
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help it was very much appreciated and went with **Yahia's** version as it gave me the most flexibility.

Comment: @mybigman you are welcome :-) please don't forget to upvote/mark as accepted any answer that was of help (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 2):

one possible way

```
SELECT DATE(crtdtime) AS cntldate, 
  sd_class, 
  sum( DATE(crtdtime) = '2011-11-16') AS created
  sum( DATE(rstdtime) = '2011-11-16') AS restored
FROM master
WHERE DATE(crtdtime) = '2011-11-16' or DATE(rstdtime) = '2011-11-16'
GROUP BY cntldate, sd_class
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
select q1.cntldate, q1.sd_class, q1.created, q2.restored 
   from  (
   SELECT DATE(crtdtime) AS cntldate, sd_class, COUNT(crtdtime) AS created
      FROM master
      WHERE DATE(crtdtime) = '2011-11-16'
      GROUP BY cntldate, sd_class
   )  q1
   inner join (
      SELECT DATE(rstdtime) AS cntldate, sd_class, COUNT(rstdtime) AS restored
         FROM master
         WHERE DATE(rstdtime) = '2011-11-16'
         GROUP BY cntldate, sd_class
  ) q2
      on q1.cntldate=q2.cntldate and q1.sdclass = q2.sdclass
```

This is Postgres syntax though, so might have to play with it to get it running with MySql

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work:

```
SELECT DATE(m1.crtdtime) AS cntldate, 
m1.sd_class, 
COUNT(m1.crtdtime) AS created , 
(
  SELECT COUNT(m2.rstdtime) 
  FROM master m2
  WHERE DATE(m2.rstdtime) = DATE(m1.rstdtime)
  and m2.sd_class=m1.sd_class
) as restored
FROM master m1
WHERE DATE(crtdtime) = '2011-11-16'
GROUP BY cntldate, sd_class
```

Answer (score 0):

It actually isn't that difficult (once you've been doing it a while). Use a SUM( IF() ) such as...

```
SELECT 
      date( if( date( ctrdtime ) = '2011-11-16', ctrdtime, rstdtime )) as CntlDate,
      sd_class,
      sum( if( date( ctrdtime ) = '2011-11-16', 1, 0 ) ) as CreatedCount,
      sum( if( date( rstdtime ) = '2011-11-16', 1, 0 ) ) as RestoredCount
   FROM 
      master
   WHERE 
         DATE(crtdtime) = '2011-11-16'
      OR DATE(rstdtime) = '2011-11-16'
   GROUP BY 
      1, 2
```

This would also work if you expanded a date range for both created and restored...